# Homology of Hirzebruch surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\mathbb{F}_n:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(-n)\oplus\mathcal{O}(0))$ be the $n$th Hirzebruch surface, where $\mathcal{O}(k)$ is the canonical line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb C$, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I'm trying to compute the intersection form associated to $\mathbb F_n$. In order to do this I need to compute its homology, and in particular, I have to check that the generators of $H_2(\mathbb F_n;\mathbb Z)$ are given by $s_\infty(\mathbb P^1), P_x$, where the notations are those used [here](http://www.boma.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/data/25print.pdf).  I would follow the paper I linked, but I don't understand what $D$ is and what the notation $D\cup_{id} (-D)$ means. Can someone help me to understand?

Comment: Were you feeling hungry when you typed "Hirzebrunch"? $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Ahahah thanks :) Anyway, just a little bit. It's  mathematics which makes me feel stupid! :)

Comment: I can not access your link, but $H_4$ for an irreducible  complex surface is just $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by the fundamental class of the surface. Did you mean $H_2$ (which is more interesting)?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It's $H_2$. Anyway, the link is that of Manifold Atlas. Try to type "Hirzebrunch surfaces manifold atlas" on google.